# axios doesn't return response and error separately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

I have a React component. Inside that component I have a function onFormSubmit that calls function from another component. This other function is making POST request with axios. 
I would like to return if POST request is true a response into first function or error if not. What is happening now is that my 'SUCCESS RESPONSE' console.log is always triggered, even then there is an error in axios POST request. If there is an error then just 'ERROR RESPONSE' console.log should be triggered.

**From first component**

```
 onFormSubmit = () => {
    postJobDescriptionQuickApply(this.state, this.props.jobDescription.id)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('SUCCESS RESPONSE', response)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('ERROR RESPONSE', error)
      })
  }
```

From second component

```
export const postJobDescriptionQuickApply = (easyApplyData, jobId) => apiUrl('easyApply', 'easyApply').then(url => axios
  .post(url, {
    applicant: {
      email: easyApplyData.email,
      fullName: `${easyApplyData.firstName} ${easyApplyData.lastName}`,
      phoneNumber: easyApplyData.phoneNumber,
      resume: easyApplyData.resume,
      source: easyApplyData.source,
    },
    job: {
      jobId,
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('SUCCESS', response.data.developerMessage)
    return response.data.developerMessage
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // handle error
    console.log('ERROR JOB DESCRIPTION', error.response.data.developerMessage)
    return error.response.data.developerMessage
  })
```

Comment: "even then there is an error in axios POST request" what exactly do you mean by that? How do you know it's an error or not? Response code?

Comment: If there is an error in axios POST request then "ERROR JOB DESCRIPTION" console.log is triggered and if it's succers then 'SUCCESS' console.log is triggered. This works fine. I just need it to triggered the same way back in first function that called it. Seaprate for error and separate for success

Answer (score 5, accepted):

calling `return` indicates success, and the `.catch` function in the calling method wouldn't be triggered. Instead of returning `error.response.data.developerMessage` use `throw` instead. This will cause it to be thrown and then caught with the `.catch` method in the calling function.

Depending on the situation though, it's generally not advisable to catch and rethrow exceptions like that because you lose stack trace etc. You may be better off not catching the error in the lower method and just relying on the calling method to handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

*Not use catch and catch on your second component.*

To can use then and catch on your first component you need return axios, something as:

```
export const postJobDescriptionQuickApply = (easyApplyData, jobId, url) => axios
  .post(url, {
    applicant: {
      email: easyApplyData.email,
      ...
    },
    job: {
      jobId,
    },
  });

// or using apiUrl

export const postJobDescriptionQuickApply = (easyApplyData, jobId) => apiUrl('easyApply', 'easyApply')
 .then(url => axios.post(url, {
    applicant: {
      email: easyApplyData.email,
      fullName: `${easyApplyData.firstName} ${easyApplyData.lastName}`,
      phoneNumber: easyApplyData.phoneNumber,
      resume: easyApplyData.resume,
      source: easyApplyData.source,
    },
    job: {
      jobId,
    },
  });
```

Additionally, do not forget to validate the response status in the first component, something as:

```
onFormSubmit = () => {
    postJobDescriptionQuickApply(this.state, this.props.jobDescription.id)
      .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
             console.log('SUCCESS RESPONSE', response);
          }

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('ERROR RESPONSE', error)
      })
  }
```

***I hope, I could help you***

Answer (score 0):

In the

```
 .catch((error) => {
   // handle error
   console.log('ERROR JOB DESCRIPTION', error.response.data.developerMessage)
   return error.response.data.developerMessage
 })
```

replace return statement with `throw error`